Empirical study of pattern recognition and prediction in stock movements
A lot of people like to look at charts of stocks, imagine they can see pictures or trends in the way the lines move, and then use that to predict what the stock is going to do in the future. Someone I know for example loves talking about a "cup and handle pattern" as evidence of something about the way the stock is going to move in the future. This apparently goes back to a book written by William McNeil called "How to Make Money in Stocks."
See e.g. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cupandhandle.asp
To me this is closer to astrology than something that will actually make people money, but I'm wondering if anyone has actually published research on it, a rebuttal to the claims in the book, or other common "technical analysis" patterns. I understand this is a bit of a  fool's errand - anyone who actually found a useful pattern would trade on it instead of selling a newsletter or whatever - but curious if someone has tried to actually show this empirically.
